# What does langchain CharacterTextSplitter's chunk_size param even do?

Tags: python, machine-learning, text, nlp, langchain

My default assumption was that the `chunk_size` parameter would set a ceiling on the size of the chunks/splits that come out of the `split_text` method, but that's clearly not right:

```
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter, CharacterTextSplitter

chunk_size = 6
chunk_overlap = 2

c_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=chunk_size, chunk_overlap=chunk_overlap)

text = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

c_splitter.split_text(text)
```

prints: `['abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz']`, i.e. one single chunk that is much larger than `chunk_size=6`.

So I understand that it didn't split the text into chunks because it never encountered the separator. But so then the question is what *is* the `chunk_size` even doing?

I checked the documentation page for `langchain.text_splitter.CharacterTextSplitter` [here](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/data_connection/document_transformers/text_splitters/character_text_splitter) but did not see an answer to this question. And I asked the "mendable" chat-with-langchain-docs search functionality, but got the answer "The chunk_size parameter of the CharacterTextSplitter determines the maximum number of characters in each chunk of text."...which is not true, as the code sample above shows.

Comment: Thank you for this question. I feel like crazy people! Now, can someone explain how to split on character count in a clean and simple manner?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

CharacterTextSplitter will only split on separator (which is '\n\n' by default). chunk_size is the maximum chunk size that will be split *if splitting is possible*. If a string starts with n characters, has a separator, and has m more characters before the next separator then the first chunk size will be n if chunk_size < n + m + len(separator).

Your example string has no matching separators so there's nothing to split on.

Basically, it attempts to make chunks that are <= chunk_size, but will still produce chunks > chunk_size if the minimum size chunks that can be created are > chunk_size.

Answer (score 8):

`CharacterTextSpliiter` behaves differently from what you expected.

```
text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(
    separator="\n",
    chunk_size=6,
)
```

It first looks for the first 6 characters and then splits the next chunk from the closest separator, not from the 7th character.

As stated in the docs default separator is "\n".

> This is the simplest method. This splits based on characters (by
> default "\n\n") and measure chunk length by number of characters.

you can test the behaviour with a sample code. first create a `test.txt` file with this

```
1.Respect for Others: Treat others with kindness.
2.Honesty and Integrity: Be truthful and act with integrity in your interactions with others.
3.Fairness and Justice: Treat people equitably.
4.Respect for Property: Respect public and private property.
5.Good Citizenship: Contribute positively to your community by obeying laws, voting, volunteering, and supporting communal well-being.
```

then write this code:

```
from langchain.document_loaders import TextLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter

# it will first find first 20 character then it will make the next chunk at the closest separator
text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(
    separator="\n",
    chunk_size=20,
    chunk_overlap=0
)

loader = TextLoader("test.txt")
docs = loader.load_and_split(
    text_splitter=text_splitter
)

for doc in docs:
    print(doc.page_content)
    print("\n")
```

this is how it look like:

[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to `CharacterTextSplitter`, `RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter` module explains with more sense to me.

**Recursively split by character**

> This text splitter is the recommended one for generic text. It is parameterized by a list of characters. It tries to **split on them in order until the chunks are small enough**. The default list is ["\n\n", "\n", " ", ""]. This has the effect of trying to **keep all paragraphs (and then sentences, and then words) together as long as possible**, as those would generically seem to be the strongest **semantically** related pieces of text.

Reference > https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/data_connection/document_transformers/text_splitters/recursive_text_splitter

Answer (score -6):

The chunk_size parameter in the CharacterTextSplitter class determines the maximum number of characters in each chunk when splitting a text into smaller chunks. Here is an explanation of the chunk_size parameter based on the provided search results:

The default value for chunk_size is 1000 tokens.
The chunk_size parameter can be set when creating an instance of the CharacterTextSplitter class.
When splitting a text into chunks, the chunk_size parameter controls the maximum number of characters in each chunk.
The chunk_size parameter is used to split a text into smaller chunks [2].
The chunk_size parameter is used to control the size of the final documents when splitting a text.
To illustrate how the chunk_size parameter is used, here is an example:

```
import { CharacterTextSplitter } from "langchain/text_splitter";
const text = "This is a sample text to be split into smaller chunks.";
const splitter = new CharacterTextSplitter({
  chunkSize: 10,
});

const output = await splitter.createDocuments([text]);
```

In this example, the chunk_size is set to 10, which means the text will be split into chunks of 10 characters each. The createDocuments method is used to split the text and returns a list of documents containing the smaller chunks.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT